# WaitFor, Ajax, and the Tester API

Tags: casperjs

If I want to use the tester API, and use say `assertSelectorExists`, how can I waitFor a selector? I understand that you could use waitForSelector's onTimeout callback and manually create a message in there but it would seem to defeat the purpose of having the ability to assert...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this?

```
casper.waitForSelector('#my-selector', function() {
    this.test.pass('selector found');
}, function() {
    this.test.fail('selector was not found');
});
```

Comment: I missed that in the API. Thanks!